# How to find Value at specific index in an array in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe with columns `SRi` and `SAi`. Each row represents a different location and these columns contain arrays of `SRi` and `SAi` for each location. I want to find the index of the maximum value of `SAi` and then find the corresponding value of `SRi` for that index, `w`. Here is a screenshot of my dataframe, called `AvgT`[image]

I'm able to find the index of the max value of `SAi` for each location (row) with the following loop but can't find the corresponding value at the same index in `SRi`. I get the error "IndexError: index out of bounds". I think what I have written is finding the value at the index of `SRi` rather than the index of each array within `SRi`. How can I fix this so that it finds the index of each array within `SRi` for each location?

```
MaxSA=[]
for index, row in AvgT.iterrows():
    maxsa=np.argmax(AvgT.SAi[index])
    w=AvgT.SRi[maxsa]
    MaxSA.append(maxsa)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line isn't doing what you think it's doing:

```
    w=AvgT.SRi[maxsa]
```

You are accessing the value of SRi in row maxsa of the dataframe -- that is, you are getting the whole list. I assume you are getting an IndexError because in at least one instance, the argmax of SAi is higher than the number of rows in your dataframe.

Try replacing that line with this:

```
    w=AvgT.SRi[index][maxsa]
```